# error LNK2001 al intentar definir y llamar un atributo static

Tags: c++, poo, static

mi problema reside en que no estoy pudiendo definir ni llamar el valor de un atributo de tipo `int` `static`. Intente definirlo externamente y tampoco me dejaba. Ya he hecho otro proyecto con atributos  `static` y no he tenido problemas, realmente no entiendo porque en este caso no estoy pudiendo resolverlo, no se si ya tengo la cabeza quemada o que. Agradezco cualquier sugerencia y/o explicación.

Dice.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef DICE_H
#define DICE_H

class Dice
{
private:
    static int id;
    int value;

public:
    Dice();
    ~Dice();

    void throw_();
    void diceForm();
    int getValue();
    int getId();
    void getInfo();
};

#endif // !DICE_H
```

Dice.cpp

```
#include "Dice.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

Dice::Dice()
{
    // Aca (y por fuera del .cpp y .h) ya probe definir id = 0; pero tampoco funciona
    id++;
    value = 0;

    srand(time(0)); 
}

int Dice::getId()
{
    return id;
}
```

Me suena a que debe ser algo básico y sencillo, pero realmente estuve un buen rato repasando las definiciones de Static y viendo distintos ejemplos, pero nada me pudo ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega al principio de Dice.cpp la instrucción:

```
int Dice::id= 0;
```

Pará definir el atributo estático.

Comment: Sabes que habia probado eso, pero sin poner el tipo de valor como `int`. Igual todavia me queda la duda de porqué en otro proyecto que utilice un atributo `static` de la misma manera, me funcionó perfecto y sin tener que definirlo previamente. Me funcionó perfecto lo que me sugeriste, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Pedro puede que le hayas dado un valor. Por eso no se quejaba. Así: `static int id = 0;`